# How to predict the units sold (or a distribution) from a sample of serial numbers?

Tags: distributions, predictive-models

A thought topic was presented to my probability class years ago (and I've long since forgot) how to determine the final unit sold (or a distribution) from a sample of serial numbers.

Example: You go to several stores and buy diapers with serial numbers the day after the end of the quarter. Now you want to know how many does this company sell in a quarter. If the number was to reset on this item at the beginning of the quarter and you have 48301, 48439, and 48536. How would you then estimate the final number of units sold in that quarter? Which distribution make sense to describe this situation?

My intuition says the number is smaller than the smallest number, but that isn't necessarily true because we would then fail to account for partial sales of a lot/store's stock. So more than likely the number is inside this range. 
Is it sufficient to take the average? 
Is there more information we can glean? 
Does in-stock inventory have an effect on our sample?

Comment: Welcome to our site! Try searching this site for the "German tank problem".

Comment: Thank you that was exactly what I was looking for, the Bayesian solution offering the mean and standard deviation.

Comment: Do you think your question is a duplicate of an existing question? If so you can use the "flag" it and a moderator can mark the question as such.